# Help removing black border on focus of input button in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In IE 7 and lower I cannot get rid of the black border that appears when a input button has focus. I have tried:

```
input:focus {
outline-width:0;
outline:none;
border: 1px solid #FFF; 
}
```

in CSS but it does not do anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set border-color to transparent to remove the border in IE. Like this:

```
input:focus{
  border: none;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

Read more about it here: http://bitesizebugs.wordpress.com/2009/08/17/border-none-not-working-on-text-input-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: This did not work for me, the black border still appears on focus

Answer (score 0):

I saw this from someone here.
the link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/39524745/12815454

```
.your_button_class:focus{
    outline=0px;
}
```

Thank you Jordi!