# How to remove the focus border of button when click?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap `button`, and I want that when I click on them the focus border should not come around the icons. The code is like below.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-link"> <img src="../images/icons/User.svg" class="svg"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: try this 
button:focus { outline:0 !important; }

Comment: Its not working bro.

Comment: Two thoughts - firstly - that border on active state / focus is an important indicator of action in terms of accessability (to allow users to know what they have done / point of focus - so take care when removing it. Secondy - the use of !important should not be recommended since it has implications throughout the entire style sheet.

Answer (score 7):

Use this style to avoid the focus border on items

```
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `outline:0;` or `outline:none;` to remove the border on focus

**Note:** Use `!important` at the end of the rule to override the Bootstrap declarations

```
button:focus{
    outline:0 !important;
}
```

or

```
button:focus{
    outline:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Try It Once**

```
button:focus{
outline:0px;
}
```

**Also Use**

```
 button:focus{
 outline:none !important;
 }
```

I have to edit !important then it work fine.

Comment: There Is No Other Answer That's why I Giving You The Same Answer

Answer (score 3):

On Bootstrap 4, "shadow-none" class was added that disables the effect.

Using JQuery you can disable the effect by adding the "shadow-none" class to the relevant buttons.

```
  $(".btn-secondary").addClass("shadow-none");
```

Answer (score 2):

Add following CSS property if none of them works -

```
box-shadow:none !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its either one or several of the following lines.

```
button {
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

I don't think you will need the `:focus` part at all as the actual bootstrap button is never showing. I don't at least. And maybe try and leave the `!important` away in case it works without it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap 4 add this class to the input or button tag

`shadow-none`

Answer (score 0):

**All previous answers all incorrect:**

Please see below for the reason, I also **added snippet** at the bottom of my answer

```
/*incorrect*/
button:focus {
outline:none !important;
}

/*correct*/
.btn.btn-link:focus {
outline:none !important;
}
```

**Please Learn more about CSS Selector about "class"**

```
class ===>  using  .

id    ===>  using  #
```

**CSS Selectors ( Also About "class")**

```
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp
```

**"class" Names Concatenated Or Separated By a Space**

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858926/class-names-concatenated-or-separated-by-a-space
```

Please check below my **example** which run in **snippet**:

```css
/*=============Button1===============*/
.button1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #c4891b;
    background-image: url('http://order.uprintinvitations.com/photothumbs/089634f1-2a24-485e-81e9-192ac6c8de07.png');
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
    background-size: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    transition: transform .5s;
}
/*for changing the colong on mouse over*/
.button1:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
/*for removing the outline*/
.button1:focus {
    outline: none;
}
/*=============Button1===============*/

.button2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #c4891b;
    background-image: url('http://order.uprintinvitations.com/photothumbs/089634f1-2a24-485e-81e9-192ac6c8de07.png');
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
    background-size: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    transition: transform .5s;
}
/*for changing the colong on mouse over*/
.button2:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Button 1
      <br>(onclick
      <br>no outline)
    </td>

    <td>
      Button 2
      <br>(onclick
      <br>outlined)
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class='button1' id='' name='' value=''></button>
    </td>

    <td>
      <button class='button2' id='' name='' value=''></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>

<a href='https://github.com/dicka-ks'>My Github -> Dicka</a>
```

https://github.com/dicka-ks

Answer (score 0):

It will work

```
.svg:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```